# CORS error in Google Maps Geocoding API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm facing a rather sudden Google Maps Geocoding issue. It was all working fine till yesterday but since then I've been getting a CORS error on any request made to their Geocoding API.

My request:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.92187618976372,72.82581567764282&key=<API_KEY>
```

My request headers:

```
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin:http://domain
Referer:http://domain/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4)AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.89 Safari/537.36
X-FirePHP-Version:0.0.6
```

Response headers:

```
access-control-allow-origin:*
alternate-protocol:443:quic,p=1
cache-control:public, max-age=86400
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:1279
content-type:application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:Thu, 23 Jul 2015 09:50:49 GMT
expires:Fri, 24 Jul 2015 09:50:49 GMT
server:mafe
status:200
vary:Accept-Language
x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

Error message:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=18.92187618976372,72.82581567764282&key=<API_KEY>. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://domain' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: @geocodezip, I solved it. Take a look below. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My system was setup in such a way that I have my front end is being served from a cross domain from my logic server.  For this, I had set my `withCredentials` flag as `true`. Since Maps' API uses a `*` wildcard, `withCredentials` was giving an error.

To solve this, I used a separate XHR method for Maps calls where the flag was set as false.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the header to null worked for me.

```
let url= `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=${payload.lat},${payload.lng}&key=${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_MAP}`;
 const res = await axios.get(url,{headers:null});
```